# Ensure that JRE is in your system path

Tags: java

How do I Ensure that JRE is in my system path?  Well, actually, I know it's not because running java -jar from the command lines produces a java is not recognized error.

How do I put JRE into my system path?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit your `PATH` variable for eg. in windows (under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\Advanced System Settings\Environment Variables

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Java6\jre\bin
```